# How do I configure phpmailer with dkim and smtp authorization on plesk?

Tags: php, phpmailer, plesk, dkim

I am running Plesk onyx along with CentOs.  The full hostname of the server is server.myHostName.com.

In Plesk, I have enabled DKIM Spam Protection to allow signing outgoing mail, and under Websites and Domains >> Mail Settings I have enabled Use DKIM spam protection system to sign outgoing email messages for myDomain.com.

Under Websites and Domains >> DNS Settings, there are 2 entries for what I think are DKIM:

_domainkey.MyDomain.com. and 
default._domainkey.MyDomain.com.

Plesk is using postfix for the smtp mailer.

I have several questions related to getting phpmailer to work with this setup.  First, I have the following in a php mail script:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {

//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.myHostName.com.com;smtp2.myHostName.com.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'secret';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->DKIM_domain = 'MyDomain.com';
$mail->DKIM_private = '/etc/domainkeys/MyDomain.com/_default';
$mail->DKIM_selector = '';
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = '';
$mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('myname@MyDomain.com', 'My Name');
$mail->addAddress('someone@somedomain.com', 'Some One');

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

I also have SMTP authorization required under relaying options.

First, I last used phpmailer 15 years ago, and only undated today because I need to user DKIM in outbound emails, and I have more questions and no answers.

1) What do I use for $mail->Host, $mail->Username, and $mail->Password?

I didn't set up an smtp server, but assume that this was done with the Plesk installation.  I do not know the smtp server names, nor the username and password.  Are the last 2 the username and password from the sending email address (myname@MyDomain.com) or something else, and what should I put in the smtp host field?

2) Regarding DKIM, my emails are getting sent to spam/junk folders by all the big providers... yahoo, outlook, etc.  The raw source indicates DKIM is either not signed ( dkim = none (message not signed) ) when sending from phpmailer, or fails ( dkim = fail (signature syntax error) ) and ( dkim = fail (no key for signature) ) when using webmail.myDomain.com.

How should the 5 DKIM fields in the script be set up?

Thanks very much.

==================================

Synchro:

When I disable phpmailer's DKIM and rely on Plesk,  the result I get from check-auth@verifier.port25.com is:

---

### DKIM check details:

Result:         permerror (key "default._domainkey.aajumpseat.com" doesn't exist)

...

DNS record(s):
   default._domainkey.aajumpseat.com. TXT (NXDOMAIN)

Any ideas?

Do I need to generate the key?  Put it somewhere?  I thought Plesk took care of all that.

Thanks.

Comment: If plesk offers DKIM signing as an option in its mail server config, use that in preference to PHPMailer’s DKIM support.

Comment: See above edited OP.  Thanks.

Comment: This really sounds like you need to read Plesk’s docs.

Comment: Actually, in addition to using Plesk's DNS entries, my provider also requires entries in their DNS panel.  Kinda quirky, but once done works like a champs.  Thanks.